# Run Shell Command with custom input

Tags: objective-c

How can i run a shell command in objective c with a variable E.G
system("thisCMD thisParam %@", username);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"thisCMD" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:username]];
```

Or if `username` isn't already a string:

```
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"thisCMD" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[username description]]];
```

Or if you want to be able to change the format specifier for each argument to something more complicated later:

```
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"thisCMD" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", username]]];
```

Comment: lets say the command someCommand usernameShouldBeHere anotherparam how do i do it then?

Comment: Change `thisCMD` to `someCommand` and construct the `NSArray` using the `arrayWithObjects` constructor.